# How to get Row count from ms sql server in Android Studio

Tags: android, sql-server

I am new to android, my code is below.  I am trying to put a row id in database programmatically to when insert a data into database.  I am trying get Row count and increase the count value but my code is no working please some one help.

```
btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        connectionClass = new ConnectionClass();
        try {
            Connection con = connectionClass.CONN();
            Statement   stmt = con.createStatement(ResultSet.TYPE_SCROLL_INSENSITIVE, ResultSet.CONCUR_READ_ONLY);
            rs = stmt.executeQuery("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t_WMM");
            int Count=0;
            if (!rs.isBeforeFirst()) {
                txt.setText("NO data");
            } else {
                while (rs.next()) {
                    Count++;
                    txt.setText(Count);
                }
                Count=0;
                rs.close();
                stmt.close();
            }
        } catch (SQLException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: First please check you are connected with database or not because your query seems fine..

Comment: did you try debugging the code?

Comment: "my code is no working" tells us nothing, what do you mean by that? Do you get an error? If so, what's the error. Do you get unexpected results? If so, what result do you expect and what is the actual result. Help us help you. Also, why do you not use an auto increment value (`identity`)? Don't try to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: First of all clear your requirement, second check if your connection is made to server, third use finally for closing connection, fourth it is not recommended to use sql code to connect to server directly in android native.

Comment: Fixed indentation.